# What is the difference between financial market and market

Tags: markets

What is the difference between financial market and market? Are they the same?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_market could be worth reading.

Comment: I read it, it says "A financial market is a market." Didn't say they are equivalent

Comment: Actually that Wikipedia had a big phrase after what you quote that either you didn't read the whole sentence or you are being selective in what you understood as the rest is the important distinction to my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Market can be more than a few types as there can be markets for food like supermarkets, flea markets and other entities for buying and selling physical goods and services. Financial markets would imply that the products have monetary values to be exchanged and may not be consumed as stocks and bonds are rarely eaten unlike food.

As JAGAnalyst points out, "A Financial market would trade in financial products such as stocks, bonds, commercial paper, options, etc. that represent an ownership or similar value position in a company, rather than consumer markets/products. Markets more broadly can be any exchange that brings together a buyer and seller. "

Comment: A Financial market would trade in financial assets such as stocks, bonds, commercial paper, options, etc. that represent an ownership or similar value position in a company, rather than consumer markets/products, sometimes referred to as "real" assets. Markets more broadly can be any exchange that brings together a buyer and seller.